# Pod not creating in ArgoCD under argo-events namespace

Tags: argo-workflows, argo, argo-events

I am trying to use Argocd to create an event source under argo-events namespace

I have sync the event source manifest and it synced but the pod and service did not create under argo-events namespace

I tried to get all pod under argo-events namespace but nothing is showing

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: EventSource
metadata:
  name: webhook
  namespace: argo-events
spec:
  service:
    ports:
      - port: 12000
        targetPort: 12000
  webhook:
new HTTP server
    example:
      port: "12000"
      endpoint: /example
      method: POST
```